# Use of lines or Text Boxes

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation

I am currently designing a financial app, which is more trendy and user-friendly, the use of lines or text boxes
?

Comment: Please look up LukeW and his work on form best practices. You'll learn a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trendy is an underline.

User friendly is a box (bordered on all sides).

https://medium.com/google-design/the-evolution-of-material-designs-text-fields-603688b3fe03

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article. Just goes to show that even with research the big guys still get it wrong. Placeholder text is sometimes mistaken for an actual input and the field gets skipped (LukeW). The new material design textfield with label inside looks exactly like a placeholder in a textfield to me. Also that the label moves on interaction is bad practice. Don't just copy what the big guys do but think for yourself and do your own research.

Answer (score 0):

What might be trendy might not be user friendly. For instance, the hamburger used to be 'trendy', however it has known usability issues. This will also depend on your main audience. what age group are they? You could test both options on your audience to get their feedback.

When in question, I'd advise you to go for the safer and more obvious choice.